# What units can be used to benchmark CPU usage? Percentage seems unhelpful

Tags: optimization, cpu-usage, terminology, workload

I regularly see coder discussions here about CPU usage and questions about reducing 'high usage', covering everything from Javascript functions to compiled C executables.

I notice that almost always people are referring to the percentage of CPU being consumed - which naturally varies hugely according to where the code is running. eg. "When I run this I get 80% CPU usage, so I need to optimise my code".

Whilst it's clear that a level of 'high CPU usage' for looping code is often a good indicator that something is wrong, and code needs to sleep a little or be refactored, I am very surprised not to be able to find a common unit of processing measurement that is used to describe intense CPU usage rather than the percentage of the author's own machine's CPU, for example.

We can easily measure memory/disk usage by an algorithm on a certain platform, but is there any easily attainable and consistent useful figure for an amount of processing that could be used to compare usage?

Are FLOPS still used in the modern world, for instance?

Comment: A metric that is sometimes used, especially by profiling tools, is the CPI rate (clocks per instruction). But percentage of CPU usage is quite useful in tracking down where most of the time is spent, which does not necessarily mean code that needs optimization.

Comment: That's a good perspective re percentage. Maybe that explains why it is used so often - just to highlight the bottlenecks & spikes in usage, rather than to convey a standalone figure.

I wonder if some simply deem it unimportant to know how much CPI is actually used when an issue of this type is being addressed, or does that itself vary according to architecture (graphics card or browser choice, for instance)?

Comment: It does depend on the underlying architecture. An instruction can take X clocks on one architecture and 2X on another. It will be very difficult to find a metric that lets you say "this piece of code is slow on every architecture" from a single test, because well, how fast the code is executed depends on the architecture. If you want something more general you may want to look at algorithms in terms of their asymptotic complexity, or in terms of an abstract computational model.

Comment: All meaningful performance numbers depend at least on the architecture of the machine, even the ratio between peak flops and attained flops (which *is* a good performance indicator, it's just fundamentally the case that in general the same code won't be optimal on all machines)

Comment: By the way as you can maybe tell from that example, there is a huge difference between "inefficient due to doing unnecessary work" (goal: minimize CPU usage, don't regress time) and "inefficient due to performing necessary work badly" (goal: maximize instr/clock, minimize time), it's hard to cover both at the same time with a single metric

Comment: This is all very helpful - thanks both. So even though "high CPU %" might vary hugely for each person using the term and their own system, it seems the expectation is to illustrate that something 'seems wrong' to the OP because their CPU is under strain at that point - rather than anyone trying to convey a metric.